# Receiving data over the network in asynchronous mode using a protocol UDP in qt

Tags: c++

I want to receive data from a socket via a UDP protocol asynchronously. I have a main thread that sends a request to the server using a UDP protocol. A response comes from the server. I want to receive this answer in a separate thread in asynchronous mode using the qt framework. I send requests on the main thread from the main() function. I accept the answer in a separate created thread. Inside the created thread, I call the function of asynchronously receiving data. Inside this function, I read the data using the framework. There are doubts about the correctness of this design. It seems to me that the asynchronous reception function is superfluous here. How do you think?

```
void IrmaUdpSender::request_receive()
{
    qDebug() << "_request_receive_";
    std::future<UipMessage*> rez = std::async(std::launch::async, [this] () {
        UipParameters uip;
        qDebug() << "recievMessage_" << QTime::currentTime();
        connect(mUdpSocket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, [this, &uip] () {
                qDebug() << "__readyRead__from_recievMessage_= ";
                while (mUdpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
                       qDebug() << "_bytesAvaliable_ = " << mUdpSocket->bytesAvailable();
                       QNetworkDatagram datagram = mUdpSocket->receiveDatagram();
                       qDebug() << "_readData_from_server_recievMessage = " << datagram.data() << datagram.data().size();
                       QByteArray arr = datagram.data();
                       u8_t* buff = reinterpret_cast<u8_t*>(arr.data());
                       qDebug() << "_befor_decode_frame_ = " << uip.type << uip.version << uip.payload[0] << uip.payload[1] << uip.payload[2] << uip.payload[3] << uip.payloadLen << uip.lvl;
                       decodeFrame(
                                   buff, datagram.data().size(),
                                   reinterpret_cast<u8_t*>(&uip.receiveBuffer),
                                   &uip.sender, &uip.type, &uip.version, uip.payload,
                                   &uip.payloadLen, 0, &uip.lvl
                       );
                       UipMessage* reply = new UipMessage(uip.receiver, uip.sender, uip.type, uip.version, *uip.payload, uip.payloadLen - 1, reinterpret_cast<char*>(uip.payload) + 1);
                       mRecievedMessages.append(reply);
                       return reply;
                       qDebug() << "_mRecievedMessages.size()_" << mRecievedMessages.size();
                       qDebug() << "_results_after_decodeFrame = " << uip.type << uip.version << uip.payload[0] << uip.payload[1] << uip.payload[2] << uip.payload[3] << uip.payloadLen << uip.lvl;
                }
                qDebug() << "_uip_parameters_from_connect_" << uip.type << uip.version << uip.payload[0] << uip.payload[1] << uip.payload[2] << uip.payload[3] << uip.payloadLen << uip.lvl;

        });                
    });
}

void IrmaUdpSender::startListen()
{
    qDebug() << "_startListen_";        
    std::thread th([this] () {
        std::cout << "_tread_is_working!_" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));               std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        request_receive();
    });
    std::cout << "_thread_id_=" << th.thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    th.join();
}
```

Comment: In QT you should not have any blocking operations in the main thread, because they will freeze your GUI. Common approach is to exec blocking operations asynchronously and emit a signal when the result is ready. Also all QT signal-slots connections are usually configured once in the constructor (with few exceptions like one shot timers, dialogs etc.)

Comment: Otherwise, it's difficult to answer your specific question without [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your code there are irrelevant classes and functions, so can't tell if they can/cannot be executed in the main thread. Also your `std::async` doesn't make sense, because you are destroying the future object just after its creation, making the code behave in a synchronous way.

Comment: Also, your slot lambda will most likely be executed after `uip` goes out of scope (and in a main thread if your `mUdpSocket` belongs to the main thread), which exhibits undefined behaviour.

Comment: `return reply;` doesn't make sense if it's inside a QT slot that is an unnamed lambda, you cannot execute it explicitly, and QT ignores return values of slots executed by event loop. The more I read, the less sense it makes, please edit the question and try to address the points above.

Comment: The function request_receive() call in new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Using an extra thread or `std::async` will not help you anything.

Just refactor this code to a simple chain of signals and slots:

```
class IrmaUdpSender : public QObject {
...

public slots:
  void readAndDecodeFrame() {
    while (mUdpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
      ...
      decodeFrame(...)
      emit receivedMessage(reply);
    }
  }

signals:
  void receivedMessage(UipMessage *);
}
```

And somewhere in your initialization code, hook up `readAndDecodeFrame` to the UDP socket:

```
QObject::connect(mUdpSocket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &IrmaUdpSender::readAndDecodeFrame);
```

If you want the `UipParameters` to persist across calls to `readAndDecodeFrame`, you can make it a plain member variable.